# PyQT5 query.next() doesn't seem to be working

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a little GUI application in Python using PyQT5 that takes orders and save them into a database.
On inserting the data, it seems to be going in but I'm never going inside the loop when trying to retrieve
Here's the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery

import sys

from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

ui, _ = loadUiType('jkp.ui')

# Declaring global variables to be used
global name, quantity, regular, xlsize, cheeze, ham

class MainApp(QMainWindow, ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.initUi()
        self.HandleButtons()

    def initUi(self):
        # Creating the database
        con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        con.setDatabaseName('clients.sqlite')

        if not con.open():
            print('Unable to connect to the database')
            sys.exit(1)

        #
        createTableQuery = QSqlQuery()
        createTableQuery.exec("""
        CREATE TABLE orders IF NOT EXISTS (
            name VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
            quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
            regular BOOLEAN,
            xlsize BOOLEAN,
            cheeze BOOLEAN,
            ham BOOLEAN,
            )
         """)

    def HandleButtons(self):
        # connecting buttons to functions
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.Inserted)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.ShowOrders)

    def Inserted(self):
        # Getting values from Gui and puttin em in variables
        name = self.lineEdit.text()
        quantity = self.spinBox.value()
        regular = self.checkBox_3.isChecked()
        xlsize = self.checkBox_4.isChecked()
        cheeze = self.checkBox.isChecked()
        ham = self.checkBox_2.isChecked()

        # Insertion
        query = QSqlQuery()
        try:
            query.exec(f""" 
            INSERT INTO orders (name, quantity, regular, xlsize, cheeze, ham) 
            VALUES('{name}','{quantity}','{regular}','{xlsize}','{cheeze}','{ham}',)
            """)
            print('inserted !')
        except:
            print('failed')

    def ShowOrders(self):
        query = QSqlQuery()

        query.first()
        print('so far so good') ### works till here ###

        while query.next():
            print('do we get here ?')
            print(
                query.value(name),
                query.value(quantity),
                query.value(regular),
                query.value(xlsize),
                query.value(cheeze),
                query.value(ham),
            )


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So upon executing the Gui appears the values entered are stored inside the variable, the insertion says 'inserted' but later on I don't know where the issue

Comment: You're not querying anything in `ShowOrders`... Try to use `print(query.first())`, and you'll see.

Comment: I get False, but how/why ?

Comment: The query isn't active because you haven't executed a SELECT statement - so `first()` and `next()` will always return `False`. But even then, your while-loop will raise a NameError because `name`, `quantity`, etc aren't defined.

Comment: PS: building statements from user input using f-strings is very bad practice because it is vulnerable sql injection attacks.  Also, datatypes like VARCHAR and BOOLEAN have no real meaning in sqlite: see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: I just did : 
query = QSqlQuery()
query.exec('SELECT name,quantity,regular,xlsize, cheeze, ham FROM orders')
print(query.first()) 
It still returns False. 
What exactly would cause the NameError ? the fact that's it's not inside the select query ?

Answer (score 2):

You have the following errors:

- You have syntax errors in SQL statements.
- Qt does not throw exceptions when some function has an internal error but uses other methods (like returning a boolean).
- It is not necessary to use global variables (also the use that the OP gives it is confusing).

```py
class MainApp(QMainWindow, ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.init_ui()
        self.handle_buttons()

    def init_ui(self):
        # Creating the database
        con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        con.setDatabaseName("clients.sqlite")

        if not con.open():
            print("Unable to connect to the database")
            sys.exit(1)

        #
        query = QSqlQuery()
        if not query.exec(
            """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (
            name VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
            quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
            regular BOOLEAN,
            xlsize BOOLEAN,
            cheeze BOOLEAN,
            ham BOOLEAN
            )
         """
        ):
            print(query.lastError().text())

    def handle_buttons(self):
        # connecting buttons to functions
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.insert)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.show_orders)

    def insert(self):
        # Getting values from Gui and puttin em in variables
        name = self.lineEdit.text()
        quantity = self.spinBox.value()
        regular = self.checkBox_3.isChecked()
        xlsize = self.checkBox_4.isChecked()
        cheeze = self.checkBox.isChecked()
        ham = self.checkBox_2.isChecked()

        # Insertion
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare(
            "INSERT INTO orders (name, quantity, regular, xlsize, cheeze, ham) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        )

        query.addBindValue(name)
        query.addBindValue(quantity)
        query.addBindValue(regular)
        query.addBindValue(xlsize)
        query.addBindValue(cheeze)
        query.addBindValue(ham)

        if not query.exec_():
            print(query.lastError().text())
            print("failed")
        else:
            print("inserted !")

    def show_orders(self):
        query = QSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM orders")
        record = query.record()
        while query.next():
            print("row")
            for i in range(record.count()):
                print(f"{record.fieldName(i)}: {query.value(i)}")
```

Comment: Amazing ! It worked like a charm, thanks for the solution and the explanations

Comment: @Laspeed please read [ask] and review the [tour]